# Improving software metrics?

Tags: c++

I recently ran [CCCC](http://cccc.sourceforge.net/) on my C++ code base and received quite a few red marks (a sample [output of CCCC on a code base (not my code base)](http://www.softeng.rl.ac.uk/media/uploads/html_pages/cccc.html) can be seen in the link). I understand that the red marks may be due to an essential complexity or an accidental complexity, but CCCC does not distinguish between the two. I am most concerned about the values of the modularity metric called "[Henry and Kafura's information flow complexity](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aserebre/2IS55/2009-2010/10.pdf)" in my code base, which has quite a few red marks. Are there any work that describes any workflow recommendations or prescriptions for reducing the number of red marks?

Answer (score 5):

These red marks are to be expected, given the classes involved.

Both `string` and `ostream` have high fan-in, but zero fan-out.  This means you are putting data into strings, or sending data to ostreams.  16 modules using `string` is not unreasonable, nor is 16 modules using `ostream`.

Your CDistribution module has moderate fan-in and fan-out, meaning that several modules send it data, and several modules receive data from it.  Presumably this is why it is called CDistributor, because it distributes something from modules to other modules without them knowing about each other directly.  Presumably this is by design.

You can remove the red mark of CDistribution by getting rid of the architecture and having modules call each other directly!  This is not a serious suggestion, of course.  Your architecture seems reasonable and having a red mark only on CDistribution indicates that you've compressed all these dependencies into one well-defined place, which is a good thing.

As for removing red marks of `string` and `ostream`, you have to reduce dependencies on these classes, but they are foundational classes.  Imagine how large the "fan-in" is on the global integer `+` operator!  Some things just get used a lot, and this is what you are seeing.

Comment: "inhibits reuse" :| Seriously, I can't attach much value to a tool that concludes `std::string` isn't reusable because it's used a lot (!)

Comment: IMHO metrics should not be considered absolute, but they are useful for comparison.  If there was red everywhere then for instance introducing CDistribution might move the red to a well-defined place.  So you could tell you'd improved things by looking at the metrics.  But the static metrics alone don't tell you that your program is "good" or "bad".  They just tell you facts about the program, which it is up to you to interpret.

Comment: How can you compare 4 and 5, if you don't know whether it's a positive or a negative measure? Or even worse, a measurement that's sometimes good and sometimes bad - like this? Facts are all too easy, and therefore cheap. Insight is valuable, and the `std::string` example shows that this tool doesn't have a lot of that.

Comment: Tools don't have insight; only people have that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, just to be clear, the included link to a sample output of cccc is not the output on my code base.

Comment: OK well I hope you get a flavour at least from my answer :)  It's not necessarily bad to have red marks, if you can justify why they appear.

Answer (score 0):

Improve the metric by improving the code. That would be the most useful and generically applicable method, IMO.

The last thing you want to do is mask metrics by some kind of filtering. Nothing is more waste of time than statistics that are lies.

Use them wisely, **but don't make it your religion**. Live with a few red marks

---

**Edit** if you really want to combat 'them red flags', the most generic adiec I can think of:

- make methods small
- group parameters in parameter objects

Of course, that will not heal isolated connected modules and what else could be wrong, but it sure is a good start to 'spreading'/'diluting' informational complexity in general